# Silverstripe Setting different default values based on page types

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have a default value set in $db array to "1". For ex :

```
class Page extends SiteTree {
   public static $defaults = array(
      "Indexing" => "1"
   );
}
```

This works fine and sets the default value very nicely. Now I have a different page type say for example :

```
 class mypage extends page{
    // Since this class extends page so it will take the default
    // value "Indexing" => "1" ..
 }
```

I want to set the default value "Indexing" => "0" in the "mypage" page type. How can I achieve that.

I have tried the following :

```
 class mypage extends page{
    public static $defaults = array(
      "Indexing" => "0"
    );
 }
```

This does not work as the parent default value is set.
Any help would be deeply appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Adding "Indexing" => "0" in the "mypage" page type has no effect to the default value for "Indexing" .. The default for Indexing is set to "1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Zauberfisch is almost to the point but I think he missed something. You must use :

```
public function populateDefaults(){
    if($this->ClassName == "mypage")
        $this->PGIndexing = "0";
    else
        $this->PGIndexing = "1";
}
```

Here you are setting the default value based on the classname. So this should work. Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks Majeed you are the BOSS.. It saved my day.. Thank you very much.

Comment: I digress, this solution is not "clean". I think you are suggesting to do this on the base class, and performing an if check there. but in an object oriented/inheritance design, the base class (parent) should never know or care about its sub classes (children). Thus, I would use my recommended solution, and only overwrite `populateDefaults` in the subclass. (But better or not, bot ways will produce the same result)

Comment: Ah, I just noticed you posted your solution before I added the example to my answer. To clarify, I added an example for `populatedDefaults` in the subclass after that to my answer, which is what I refer to as "my recommended solution"

Comment: @Zauberfisch I have added the above solution in the subclass and not in the Base class. I agree the fact that base class is unknown of the subclass. I have added the above mentioned code by "Majeed" in the "mypage" page type class. It is working fine. Though your answer is also correct. Thanks for your support. I appreciate you for that.

Comment: This method doesn't allow for other defaults to be set and doesn't return the current DataObject as the parent method does. I'd suggest @Zauberfisch solution which is cleaner and keeps all functionality.

Answer (score 1):

obviously this will error, because $db is not for setting values, it is the database definition of silverstripe.

if it works without an error then you either have not pasted the complete code, or there is a bug in silverstripe that lets you get a way with this faulty syntax.

either way, her is how its done:

```
class Page extends SiteTree {
    // public static for SilverStripe 3.x, private static for 3.1+
    public static $db = array(
        "Indexing" => "Int",
    );
    public static $defaults = array(
        "Indexing" => 1,
    );
}
```

now that was the base class, for the child class, I am not a 100% sure that overwriting the default value actually works, but give it a try, if it doesn't, you have to overwrite the `populateDefaults` method and set it there.

```
class OtherPage extends Page {
    public static $defaults = array(
        "Indexing" => 2,
    );
}
```

---

alternatively, if that does not work, you have to overwrite `populateDefaults` as mentioned above.
`populateDefaults` is the method that usually reads the $defaults variable and sets some system defaults.

```
class OtherPage extends Page {
    public function populateDefaults() {
        $return = parent::populateDefaults();
        $this->Indexing = 2;
        return $return;
    }
}
```

note, that in all cases (`$defaults` and `populateDefaults()`) it is ONLY run when the record is FIRST CREATED.
this also means that if you already have a record, and you add a field like Indexing later on, it will NOT effect existing records, those will have a value of NULL, 0, empty string and so on depending on the data type.

Comment: I tried the way you explained above but that is not setting the value in mypage page type.. It is taking the default value which is set in base class. Any other Idea ??

Comment: yes, as I mentioned, then you probably have to overwrite `populateDefaults`. I will edit the answer to also provide an example for that.